# Trying to figure out what "table-reflow" actually does in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, definition, reflow

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/ (last example at the bottom of the page)

There is no description in the example, I am having a hard time figuring out what this is actually doing to the table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Bootstrap 4 to make a table's contents reflow.

See, in the following example, how the header cells are all positioned in the left column now, rather than along the top row (as in the previous example). Both examples use the same table markup. The only difference is the .table-reflow class has been added to the second example.

To make a table reflow, add Bootstrap's .table-reflow class to the .table class.

http://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/tutorial/bootstrap_tables.cfm

Answer (score 0):

This feature is removed from Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 though, not sure whether it will be implemented again.